# How can I determine if an iOS device has come back into Network coverage if the user has closed the app?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

We are building an enterprise class Work Order application where the users will often be in areas with no network coverage.  We want to be sure that when they come back into coverage, any work that they have done on locally stored work orders is sent back to the server ASAP.  This is easy to do if the user keeps the app running, but in our situation it is very likely that they will switch between apps, and the Work Order app may not be running when they come back into coverage.

We have thought of having the app fire an email to a server side listener when it senses that it is out of coverage.  When the device comes back into coverage, the email should get delivered, and the server can send a push notification to the user to open the app.  This feels like a bit of a hack...  is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: It's a hack, but it's pretty clever if it works.

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, push notifications is the way to go, but even with them its not guaranteed that the user will send the data or even open the app.

I would suggest that you make the data itself expire after a limited time and alert the users when they minimize or even close the application.

You can also use local notification to alert about expiration.

Answer (score 0):

So long as this is an enterprise application that doesn't have to be distributed through the App Store, you can abuse the audio background processing mode to keep your application running at all times.  All you have to do is play a silent audio file on a loop as if you were a media player.  This will keep your application running in the background, where you can retry connections to the server as you'd like.